$3$ sheeted covers of $\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee S^1$
Using covering spaces, show that there are three subgroups of index $3$ of $G = \mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}$. This is a problem from a qualifying exam.
Let $X = \mathbb{R}P^2 \vee S^1$. Then, $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee S^1) = G$. I know that that index $3$ subgroups of $G$ are in bijection with $3$ sheeted covers of $X$, which are in bijection with conjugacy classes of of the group $H = \text{Hom}(G, S_3)$, where the conjugacy classes are defined as: $\rho \sim \rho' \iff \exists h \text{ such that } h^{-1}\rho(x) h = \rho'(x)$ for each $x \in G$.
Let $a$ and $b$ denote the identity elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ respectively. Elements of $H$ are precisely maps that take $a$ to $1$ or some transposition, and $b$ to any element in $S_3$. I can right away see at least four conjugacy classes in $H$ that take $(a,b)$ to $(1,1), (1,(12)), ((12), 1), ((12),(12))$ respectively, and it is not hard to see that these belong to distinct classes.
This contradicts the fact there there should be only $3$ such classes. Where did I go wrong?
A full solution would also be appreciated.

Index $3$ subgroups come from maps $G$ to $S_3$ where the image is a transitive subgroup.

Let $G\cong\langle a,b\mid a^2=1\rangle$. The index $3$ subgroups come from maps $G\rightarrow S_3$ whose image is a transitive subgroup: then the index $3$ subgroup (up to conjugacy) is the pre-image of a point stabilizer. There are three such maps to think about:

The map $a\mapsto(1)$ and $b\mapsto(123)$. In this case the point stabilizer is trivial, so the kernel is the index $3$ subgroup. This is the only normal index $3$ subgroup.
The map $a\mapsto(12)$ and $b\mapsto(123)$. The index $3$ subgroup (up to conjugacy) is the preimage of $(12)$ [so contains $a$].
The map $a\mapsto(12)$ and $b\mapsto(13)$. The index $3$ subgroup (up to conjugacy) is the preimage of $(12)$ [so again contains $a$].

To do this with covering maps, note that $\mathbb{RP}^2\vee S^1$ as CW-complex is just the wedge of two circles (labelled $a$ and $b$) and then we attach a disk along $a^2$. So three-sheeted covering spaces are graphs with $3$ vertices, with an incoming & outgoing $a$ and $b$ edge at each vertex, and then we attach $3$ disks along disjoint $a^2$ paths. We can see three of these, corresponding to the maps above (see pictures at end of post). Note that I didn't draw the attaching disk maps, but when attaching to a circle labeled $a$, we get an $\mathbb{RP}^2$, and when attach two disks to an $a^2$ path (that touches two vertices) we get a sphere $S^2$. These coverings are (in the same order as the maps above):

In the first, we have a regular covering. We can read off the generators for this subgroup from the loops in the graph at one of the vertices. We get $\langle a,b^{-1}ab,b^{-2}ab^2,b^3\rangle$. We can also use the covering space to see that this group is isomorphic to $C_2\ast C_2\ast C_2\ast C_\infty$.
In the second, we don't have a regular covering, but we can still read off the generators and see the isomorphism type. We get $\langle a,b^3,bab\rangle$, isomorphic to $C_2\ast C_\infty\ast C_\infty$.
Similarly, in the third case, we see the subgroup is $\langle a,b^2,babab\rangle$, and it also has isomoprhism type $C_2\ast C_\infty\ast C_\infty$.




